# ComboBox: getSelectedIndex() misbehaves on 'Reselect'

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

The identifier for my combo box is `cmbYear`.

Items are 1800, 1801, 1802, 1803, ... ... ..., 2017, 2018.

Then I run the project. When I select 1801 in the user interface, the `getSelectedIndex()` returns 1 (as printed in console), which is right.

In the same run, if I again select, say, 1802, the `getSelectedIndex()` still returns 1. In every subsequent selection, the `getSelectedIndex()` returns 1, that is the first selected index.

`getSelectedIndex()` is called from `cmbYearActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)` method.

How can I fix this misbehavior, please?

Below are the related lines.

```
 /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package agecalcagain.UI;

import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.util.Calendar;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;

/**
 *
 * @author MuhammadRaselParvej
 */
public class AgeCalcAgain extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private Integer[] yearList;
    private Integer[] dayList;
    private int selectedMonthIndex=0;
    private int selectedYearIndex=0;

    private void newMonthIndex(){
       selectedMonthIndex = cmbMonth.getSelectedIndex(); 
       System.out.println("Yes, new month :"+ String.valueOf(months[selectedMonthIndex]));
    }

    private void newYearIndex(){
        selectedYearIndex = cmbYear.getSelectedIndex();
        System.out.println("Yes, new year :"+ yearList[selectedYearIndex]);
    }

    int p=1;

    Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
    String months[] = new String[]{"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
        "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};
    String eras[] = new String[]{"BC", "AD"};

    /**
     * Creates new form AgeCalcAgain
     */
    private void updateYearList() {
        int n = today.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        n = n - 1800 + 1;
        yearList = new Integer[n];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            yearList[i] = 1800 + i;
        }
    }

    private void updateDayList() {
        System.out.println("In updateDayList **************** "+ p++);
        int n = yearList[selectedYearIndex];
        System.out.println("n "+n);
        n = n % 100 == 0 ? n / 100 : n;
        System.out.println("n "+n);
        int m;
        m = selectedMonthIndex;
        m++;
        System.out.println("m "+m);
        int numberOfDays = 28;
        if (m == 2 && n % 4 == 0) {
            numberOfDays++;
        } else if (m != 2) {
            numberOfDays += 2;
        }
        if (m == 1 || m == 3 || m == 5 || m == 7 || m == 8 || m == 10 || m == 12) {
            numberOfDays++;
        }
        dayList = new Integer[numberOfDays];
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDays; i++) {
            dayList[i] = i + 1;
        }
        System.out.println(numberOfDays);
    }

    private void createTempCmbMonth() {
        cmbMonth = new JComboBox<String>(months);
    }

    private void createTempCmbYear() {
        cmbYear = new JComboBox<>(yearList);
    }

    public AgeCalcAgain() {
        updateYearList();
        createTempCmbYear();
        createTempCmbMonth();
        updateDayList();
        myInitComponents();

        this.lbl01.setText("Today is " + today.get(Calendar.DATE) + " "
                + months[today.get(Calendar.MONTH)] + ", " + today.get(Calendar.YEAR) + " " + eras[today.get(Calendar.ERA)]);

    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        lbl01 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        cmbDay = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
        cmbYear = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
        cmbMonth = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(500, 500));
        setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(500, 500));
        getContentPane().setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

        lbl01.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Narrow", 0, 20)); // NOI18N
        lbl01.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lbl01.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(), javax.swing.BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(), javax.swing.BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder()), javax.swing.BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder())));
        getContentPane().add(lbl01, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(70, 30, 270, 20));

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Narrow", 0, 20)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jLabel1.setText("Enter Your Birthdate");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(120, 70, 180, 20));

        jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Narrow", 0, 20)); // NOI18N
        jLabel2.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jLabel2.setText("Birthday");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel2, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(120, 200, 80, -1));

        jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Narrow", 0, 20)); // NOI18N
        jLabel3.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jLabel3.setText("Birthyear");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel3, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(120, 110, 80, 30));

        jLabel4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Narrow", 0, 20)); // NOI18N
        jLabel4.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jLabel4.setText("Birthmonth");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel4, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(120, 150, 80, 30));

        cmbDay.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Narrow", 0, 20)); // NOI18N
        cmbDay.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(dayList));
        cmbDay.setSelectedItem(1);
        cmbDay.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                cmbDayActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(cmbDay, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(210, 200, 120, 30));

        cmbYear.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Narrow", 0, 20)); // NOI18N
        cmbYear.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(yearList));
        cmbYear.setSelectedItem(yearList[selectedYearIndex]);
        cmbYear.addItemListener(new java.awt.event.ItemListener() {
            public void itemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {
                cmbYearItemStateChanged(evt);
            }
        });
        cmbYear.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                cmbYearActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(cmbYear, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(210, 110, 120, 30));

        cmbMonth.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Narrow", 0, 20)); // NOI18N
        cmbMonth.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(months));
        cmbMonth.setSelectedItem(months[selectedMonthIndex]);
        cmbMonth.addItemListener(new java.awt.event.ItemListener() {
            public void itemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {
                cmbMonthItemStateChanged(evt);
            }
        });
        cmbMonth.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                cmbMonthActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        cmbMonth.addPropertyChangeListener(new java.beans.PropertyChangeListener() {
            public void propertyChange(java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                cmbMonthPropertyChange(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(cmbMonth, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(210, 150, 120, 30));

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void myInitComponents() {

        lbl01 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        cmbDay = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
        cmbYear = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
        cmbMonth = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(500, 500));
        setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(500, 500));
        getContentPane().setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

        lbl01.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Narrow", 0, 20)); // NOI18N
        lbl01.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lbl01.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(), javax.swing.BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(), javax.swing.BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder()), javax.swing.BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder())));
        getContentPane().add(lbl01, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(70, 30, 270, 20));

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Narrow", 0, 20)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jLabel1.setText("Enter Your Birthdate");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(120, 70, 180, 20));

        jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Narrow", 0, 20)); // NOI18N
        jLabel2.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jLabel2.setText("Birthday");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel2, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(120, 200, 80, -1));

        jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Narrow", 0, 20)); // NOI18N
        jLabel3.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jLabel3.setText("Birthyear");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel3, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(120, 110, 80, 30));

        jLabel4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Narrow", 0, 20)); // NOI18N
        jLabel4.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jLabel4.setText("Birthmonth");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel4, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(120, 150, 80, 30));



        cmbYear.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Narrow", 0, 20)); // NOI18N
        cmbYear.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(yearList));
        cmbYear.setSelectedItem(yearList[selectedYearIndex]);
        cmbYear.addItemListener(new java.awt.event.ItemListener() {
            public void itemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {
                cmbYearItemStateChanged(evt);
            }
        });
        cmbYear.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                cmbYearActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(cmbYear, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(210, 110, 120, 30));

        cmbMonth.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Narrow", 0, 20)); // NOI18N
        cmbMonth.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(months));
        cmbMonth.setSelectedItem(months[selectedMonthIndex]);
        cmbMonth.addItemListener(new java.awt.event.ItemListener() {
            public void itemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {
                cmbMonthItemStateChanged(evt);
            }
        });
        cmbMonth.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                cmbMonthActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        cmbMonth.addPropertyChangeListener(new java.beans.PropertyChangeListener() {
            public void propertyChange(java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                cmbMonthPropertyChange(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(cmbMonth, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(210, 150, 120, 30));


        cmbDay.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Narrow", 0, 20)); // NOI18N
        cmbDay.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(dayList));
        cmbDay.setSelectedItem(1);
        cmbDay.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                cmbDayActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(cmbDay, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(210, 200, 120, 30));

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        



    private void cmbYearActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        newYearIndex();
        updateDayList();
        myInitComponents();

    }                                       


    private void cmbMonthActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        newMonthIndex();
        updateDayList();
        myInitComponents();
    }                                        

    private void cmbDayActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                      

    private void cmbMonthPropertyChange(java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent evt) {                                        
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                       

    private void cmbMonthItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                          
               // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                         

    private void cmbYearItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:

    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AgeCalcAgain.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AgeCalcAgain.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AgeCalcAgain.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AgeCalcAgain.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new AgeCalcAgain().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JComboBox<Integer> cmbDay;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> cmbMonth;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox<Integer> cmbYear;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lbl01;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: `"How can I fix this misbehavior, please?"` -- you're asking why unshown code is misbehaving, a very difficult question to answer. Why not show the pertinent code? Best to create and post a valid [mcve].

Comment: Show the code in the post: which is creating the combo box, populating it and using it (the listeners, etc).

Comment: BTW for a year field I'd tend to use a `JSpinner` with a `SpinnerNumberModel` - or for a complete date, a `SpinnerDateModel'.

Comment: Here is some notes and examples at Oracle's Java tutorials about [using combo boxes in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html).

Comment: @prasad_ *"Show the code in the post: which is .."* An MCVE is what's best here, and in all questions related to actual code.

Comment: @prasad_ *"Oracle's Java tutorials"* Excellent suggestion! Folks should best go through the relevant tutorial(s) when they strike a problem or unexpected behavior (as well as before they *start* coding in any new area of the API).

Comment: I have added a link to the code.

Comment: Please no links. All pertinent code should be in your question. Understand that many of us are blocked behind firewalls and can't get to links, also links are by their nature unstable, and the code can disappear.  All code must be in the question itself. -- please read the [help] and the [ask] to find out how to better ask questions and use this site.

Comment: What is the method `cmbYearActionPerformed` doing (in your code)?

Comment: Also you're posting a heck of a lot of code in that link, most of it completely unrelated to the problem at hand. Again we want you to post a new program, a [mcve] that distills your problem into the smallest code required to run and reproduce it. You want to make is as easy as possible for others to read and understand the code as possible -- remember that we're volunteers. Please read the link (which has been posted in comments now several times).

Comment: @prasad_: it's doing this: `myInitComponents()` and this is likely causing the original poster's problem. Muhammad, don't create completely new GUI components in this way. Instead re-set the original components back to their original state. This is causing your problem.

Comment: "Also you're posting a heck of a lot of code in that link, " Sorry! I will be careful in this issue from next on.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels I can read the code and understand. I am _suggesting_ to the OP that he try to understand what _his_ code is doing ;) It is not that I can't answer the question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do **not** call `myInitComponents()` in your listener since in this method you create completely new GUI components, all set to their initial state, and this is causing you big problems. Instead write code that sets the current components back to their initial state (or to whatever state you desire).